# I need help: Missing WatchKit Extension in Xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode, watchkit, xcode14

I want to use WatchConnectivity but I can't use it without WatchKit Extension

I haven't found a solution so far

Answer (score 0):

With the update of Xcode 14, the WatchKit App and App Extension files are combined into a single Watch app target.

> Xcode 14 includes a default template for watchOS apps that combines the WatchKit App and WatchKit App Extension targets into a single Watch App target, simplifying code, asset, and localization management. You can deploy single-target watchOS apps to watchOS 7 and later. (83222217)

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes